# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Fragewörtern "wieso", "weshalb" und "warum"? 

Tags: meaning, word-usage, interrogative

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen den Fragewörtern "wieso", "weshalb" und "warum"? Ist er regional, gibt es subtile Unterschiede in den Bedeutungen, oder gibt es noch einen anderen Grund für die Existenz so vieler ähnlicher Fragewörter?

Comment: ...wer nicht fragt bleibt dumm.

Comment: Außerdem praktisch synonym: _weswegen_

Comment: *Wofür* wäre auch noch hinzuzufügen, wobei das nur die Teilbedeutung der Frage nach der Intention (nicht nach allgemeinen Ursachen) abdeckt.

Comment: Interessante Links zu Studien warum vs. wieso : https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74025/when-should-i-use-the-different-types-of-why-and-because-in-german

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Es gibt im heutigen Deutschen **keinen semantischen Unterschied** zwischen den drei Frageadverbien (genauer: Kausalfrageadverbien) *warum*, *weshalb* und *wieso*. Die drei Wörter sind also Synonyme und somit beliebig gegeneinander austauschbar.

Wenn man sehr feinsinnig ist, könnte man im Ursprung der drei Wörter folgende Unterscheidung finden:

- *warum* als Frage nach dem *Grund* oder dem *Motiv*

  > Warum freut sich die Frau?
  >   Weil sie im Lotto gewonnen hat.
- *wieso* als Frage nach der *Ursache*

  > Wieso fällt ein Apfel auf den Boden?
  >   Weil er der Schwerkraft ausgesetzt ist.
- *weshalb* als Frage nach dem *Zweck*

  > Weshalb besucht er die Schule?
  >   Weil er etwas lernen möchte.

**Etymologie**

- *warum*
  bezeugt im Althochdeutschen *wār umbe* über Mittelhochdeutschen *warumbe* aus *wār wo* und *umbe* um. Gleichgestellt zu *worum*; Quelle: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW07563)
- *wieso*
  Übertragung aus dem lateinischen *qui sic?* → *wie so?* alt. Ital. *per che?*, modern Ital.: *perché?* = *per che ragione?* ("aus welchem Grund"); Quelle: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW07563)
- *weshalb*
  *aus welchem Grunde* – Verschmelzung der Präposition *halb(en)* (*wegen*) mit dem vorangestellten Genitiv des Pronomens *was*; Quelle: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW18237)

Allerdings sind die Grenzen zwischen den Begriffen häufig verwischt und in der Alltagssprache wird diese Unterscheidung kaum wahrgenommen.

Was die Verwendung in Publikationen betrifft, zeigt Googles Ngram Viewer folgende Verteilung in der Vergangenheit und Gegenwart auf.

[image: Frageadverbien warum wieso weshalb Verteilung]

*warum* wird eindeutig bevorzugt; *wieso* hört man meiner subjektiven Erfahrung nach in mündlichen Unterhaltungen öfter, als man es in geschriebener Form findet.

Comment: Interessant. :) Aber woher nimmst Du die feinen Unterschiede? Sind das Deine eigenen Gedanken oder gibt es dafür Belege?

Comment: @elena Wenn man die Etymologie der Wörter untersucht, wird das ersichtlich. Ich habe die Antwort mit der Herkunft der einzelnen Wörter ergänzt.

Comment: Die Graphik ist nicht uninteressant, nach jedem Weltkrieg ein kleines "Warum"-Hügelchen. Ist das auf Englisch auch so?

Comment: @Phira gut beobachtet! Im Englischen scheint das Phänomen für den 2. WK auch zu gelten: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=why&year_start=1910&year_end=1960&corpus=0&smoothing=1

Comment: I gotta say I disagree respectfully. Just going by feel: wieso = can be informal. Also expresses contradiction. (Think: a kid complaining, "Whyyyy?") warum = current contemporary standard. weshalb = formal speech and writing.

Comment: Die notwendige Feinsinnigkeit, um deine "Unterschiede" nachvollziehen zu können, muss anscheinend schon in den mikroskopischen Bereich gehen. Ich kann alle drei Wörter ohne einen für mich erkennbaren Bedeutungsunterschied in allen deinen drei Beispielen einsetzen - Anscheinend  geht mir hier entweder die Feinsinnigkeit ab, oder die Unterschiede sind nicht vorhanden.

Comment: Ein Unterschied zwischen diesen Frageworten ist, dass es für 2 davon einen banalen Antwortbegriff mit der Bedeutung "ist eben so" bzw. "sage ich nicht/geht Dich nichts an" gibt: warum? - darum! bzw. weshalb? - deshalb! Bei wieso fehlt das entsprechende Gegenwort. Auf die Bedeutung der Frageworte selbst hat dies jedoch keine Auswirkung.

Comment: Wie schon erwähnt wurde kommt Wieso in der gesprochenen Umgangssprache häufig vor. Warum ist der Standard in geschriebener Sprache, welche die Standardsprache ist. Weshalb kommt seltener vor und verorte ich in der Hochsprache.

Answer (score 4):

- **Wes-wegen** = weshalben (Grimm Wörterbuch) = wessen halber = Von wessen Seite her = Von welchem Gegenstands Seite her.
  Die Präposition "halber" bedeutet "wegen" und ist mit "halb" verwandt. Das althochdeutsche "halba" bedeutete "Hälfte, Seite" - "Meinethalben" z. B. ist im Sinne "von meiner Seite her" zu verstehen.
  Weswegen fragt nach dem sichtbaren äußeren Gegenstand, der etwas hervorruft, unter dem ein Mensch leidet im Wolff‘s Sinn. (Grimm) –  **Welcher Gegenstand ist die andere Hälfte der Beziehung?**
- **Warum** = Frage nach dem Beweggrund, dem Bedürfnis der nicht sichtbar ist, der innewohnenden Kraft. - **Welche Kraft liegt der Bewegung zu Grunde?**
- **Wieso** = Wie kommt es so, wie ich es beobachte = Frage nach dem Erklärungsgrundsatz, der Ursache Wirkung Beziehung, dem Naturgesetz, der Regel, dem Gesetz, auch der seelischen Regel – **Welcher Regel gehorcht die Beobachtung?**
- **Wozu = Zu welchem Zweck?**

Answer (score 3):

"Wieso" literally translates into "how so." In this case, one is interested in the **mechanic.**

"Warum" and "weshalb" both translate into "why?" But there is a slight difference.

"Weshalb" means "how did this come about?" I believe that the operative German word is **Herkunft.**

"Warum" means "for what **reason?**" Here the German word might be **Grund.**

Answer (score 1):

warum (kausal), weshalb, weswegen (intentional), wieso (operational)

Weshalb will sie gewinnen? Sie will gewinnen, um einen Preis zu bekommen.
                                              (weil sie einen Preis bekommen möchte)

Warum freut sie sich? Sie freut sich, weil sie einen Preis gewonnen hat.
                                      (darüber dass sie einen Preis bekommen hat)

Wieso hat sie, obwohl sie gewonnen hat, keinen Preis bekommen?

Wieso fragt (auf einer Meta-Ebene) nach einer Erklärung für das Ausbleiben der Wirkung trotz Vorliegens der für die Wirkung vermeintlich hinreichenden Ursachen.

Answer (score 1):

i experience *warum/wieso/weshalb/weswegen* being intercbanged like ambivalent synonyms rather than clearly distinguished questions.  hence i resort to *wodurch/woher* to inquire causation and *wofür/wozu* for purpose.