# Different ways to say "why"

Tags: word-choice, question

> This question also has an answer here (in German):
> [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Fragewörtern "wieso", "weshalb" und "warum"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3230)

I know that there are multiple different words for "why" in German:

- warum?
- wieso?
- weshalb?
- weswegen?

Are they all interchangeable or are some more formal than others or something like that?

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3230/6495

Comment: They are synonyms. If there are differences they are so nuanced that most native speakers are not consciously aware of them.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPHi5xn_q5c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the English translation of [an old German answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3231/1487) given by the user [splattne](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44/splattne) in 2011.
The word "weswegen" was not topic of the [original German question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3230/1487), but it fits into the same scheme.

---

There is **no semantic difference** in today's German between the three interrogative adverbs (more precisely: causal interrogative adverbs) *warum, weshalb* and *wieso.* The three words are therefore synonyms and thus arbitrarily interchangeable.

If one is very subtle, one could find the following distinction in the origin of the three words:

- *warum* as a question about the reason or motive

  > Warum freut sich die Frau?
  > Weil sie im Lotto gewonnen hat.
  >
  > Why is the woman happy?
  > Because she won the lottery.
- *wieso* as a question about the cause

  > Wieso fällt ein Apfel auf den Boden?
  > Weil er der Schwerkraft ausgesetzt ist.
  >
  > Why does an apple fall to the ground?
  > Because it is exposed to the force of gravity.
- *weshalb* as a question about the purpose

  > Weshalb besucht er die Schule?
  > Weil er etwas lernen möchte.
  >
  > Why does he go to school?
  > Because he wants to learn something.

**Etymology**

- *warum* attested in Old High German *wār umbe* via Middle High German *warumbe* from *wār wo* and *umbe um.* Equated to *worum*; source: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW07563)
- *wieso*
  Transfer from Latin *qui sic? (like this?)* → *wie so* alt. Ital. *per che?,* modern Ital.: *perché? = per che ragione?* ("for what reason"); source: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW07563)
- *weshalb*
  *aus welchem Grunde (for what reason)* - merging of the preposition *halb(en)* (because of) with the prefixed genitive of the pronoun *was (what)* source: [Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW18237)

However, the boundaries between the terms are often blurred and in everyday language this distinction is hardly noticed.

As far as usage in publications is concerned, Google's Ngram Viewer shows the following distribution in the past and present.

[image: Question adverbs warum wieso weshalb distribution]

*warum* is clearly preferred; *wieso*, in my subjective experience, one hears more often in oral conversations than one finds in written form.

Comment: As a German native speaker this was very interesting to read as well.